# cannot use wget command from a user I created

Tags: apt, permissions, sudo, wget, user-management

## background

I got hold of an ubuntu box on AWS, and I was following the [instructions](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/prod-ubuntu-16.04.html) to install a mattermost server. Things were going smooth until I reached this part:

> For the purposes of this guide we will assume this server has an IP
>   address of 10.10.10.2 (note: i'm using local host instead ie 127.0.0.0)
>
> 1. Create a user and group for running mattermost:
>
> sudo useradd --create-home --user-group --system mattermost
>
> 2. Change to the account of the new user:
>
> sudo --user=mattermost --shell
>
> 3. Change into the home of the new user:
>
> cd
>
> Download any version of the Mattermost Server by typing:
>
> wget
>   https://releases.mattermost.com/X.X.X/mattermost-X.X.X-linux-amd64.tar.gz

The last link should be [replaced](https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/upgrade.html#version-archive) by this one

https://releases.mattermost.com/3.6.0/mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz

which naturally can be easily downloaded from chrome.

## problem

When I try to download that file from CLI:

```
wget https://releases.mattermost.com/X.X.X/mattermost-X.X.X-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

I get the following:

> --2017-01-17 07:22:36--  https://releases.mattermost.com/X.X.X/mattermost-X.X.X-linux-amd64.tar.gz
>   Resolving releases.mattermost.com (releases.mattermost.com)...
>   54.192.192.48, 54.192.192.69, 54.192.192.118, ... Connecting to releases.mattermost.com
>   (releases.mattermost.com)|54.192.192.48|:443... connected. HTTP
>   request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2017-01-17 07:22:36
>   ERROR 403: Forbidden.

## what I have tried

At this point I obviously don't have a password for the user `mattermost`.. so I exit the shell and give them a password:

```
$ sudo passwd mattermost
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

but then when I jump back to the `mattermost` shell and try to be a wise guy:

```
$ sudo wget https://releases.mattermost.com/3.6.0/mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[sudo] password for mattermost:
mattermost is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

So i'm not exactly sure what to do here. Why do I need to be sudo to download a publicly available file anyways?

note: i just realized that the same error happens even if i'm root on that aws box

Comment: You can download the file as any user, just make sure the directory is writable by the user. For example, do: `wget -P /tmp https://releases.mattermost.com/3.6.0/mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz` to save in `/tmp/`. Also every user has write permission on his/her home, perhaps you are running from a directory that the user does not have permission to write on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems.

### "403 Forbidden" is a web server error. You have to fix your URL.

When you ran `wget https://releases.mattermost.com/X.X.X/mattermost-X.X.X-linux-amd64.tar.gz`, you got a `403: Forbidden` error. This is an error **from the web server** and is unrelated to the user account used to download the file.

When you attempt to load a page or download a file and you specify an incorrect URL, a `404: Not Found` errors is the most common result. But a 403 error can occur sometimes in this situation, and that appears to be what is happening here. It looks, from both the command you ran and `wget`'s output, like **you forgot to put the actual version numbers in the URL**.

On my system, I am able to get exactly the same error using the URL with `X.X.X` instead of an actual version number:

```
ek@Io:~/Downloads$ wget https://releases.mattermost.com/X.X.X/mattermost-X.X.X-linux-amd64.tar.gz
--2017-01-17 03:15:30--  https://releases.mattermost.com/X.X.X/mattermost-X.X.X-linux-amd64.tar.gz
Resolving releases.mattermost.com (releases.mattermost.com)... 54.192.147.30, 54.192.147.18, 54.192.147.46, ...
Connecting to releases.mattermost.com (releases.mattermost.com)|54.192.147.30|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-01-17 03:15:32 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

And if I use the correct URL, it works:

```
ek@Io:~/Downloads$ wget https://releases.mattermost.com/3.6.0/mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
--2017-01-17 03:09:50--  https://releases.mattermost.com/3.6.0/mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
Resolving releases.mattermost.com (releases.mattermost.com)... 54.192.147.156, 54.192.147.30, 54.192.147.160, ...
Connecting to releases.mattermost.com (releases.mattermost.com)|54.192.147.156|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 27221349 (26M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz’

mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux- 100%[==============================================>]  25.96M   106KB/s    in 2m 6s

2017-01-17 03:11:58 (212 KB/s) - ‘mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz’ saved [27221349/27221349]
```

(Both the working and non-working URLs are from your post. I don't actually know exactly what file *you* need.)

### The mattermost user isn't a sudoer.

Not all users may run programs as root (or at all) with the `sudo` command.  The file `/etc/sudoers`, or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, must be configured to allow them to do so. Most commonly, this is achieved by putting the user in a group that one of those files permits to run commands.

In particular, to make a user an administrator on an Ubuntu system so that they are permitted to run any command as root using `sudo`, add the user to the `sudo` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo mattermost
```

Of course, you must run that as a user who *can* run commands as root with `sudo` already. (You were able to run `sudo passwd mattermost`, so I know you have at least one such user.)

Keep in mind:

- You must only do this if you really want that user to have *full power* to do anything. They will have the same power as you. Once you've decided you want that, though, you should go ahead and simply add the user to the `sudoers` group. There is usually no need to actually edit any configuration files for `sudo` -- they're already set up to recognize the `sudo` group as conferring administrative power.
- If for some reason you instead choose to edit `/etc/sudoers` or create/edit a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, it is important that you use the `visudo` utility to do it, because it performs a syntax check to make sure your changes will be understood by `sudo`. If `sudo` sees incorrect syntax in a sudoers file, then it will *completely refuse to work*. For servers you only have remote access to, this can lock you out of the system.

Finally, it's very rare that you actually have to manually download a file with `wget` as root. In this case, you didn't -- the error was an incorrect URL and the "forbidden" message was from  the web server. Therefore:

- If this is the only reason mattermost needed to use `sudo`, you probably shouldn't give that user account these abilities, because there's no need.
- Even if mattermost really does need to be an administrator, they should perform actions as themselves (without `sudo`) rather than as root (with `sudo`) except when there is a clear reason to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually two separate errors:

1. The `wget` command is not on your side but server-side, i.e. you don’t have access to that file on the web server (the 403 means that the client is denied acces). Now when I test `wget https://releases.mattermost.com/3.6.0/mattermost-team-3.6.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz` it works, som maybe it was just some temporary thing. But still, a 403 error is that the server does not allow you to access the url.
2. The sudo issue is a completely different story. When you install Ubuntu you create a user during the installation process. That user is the only one able to sudo, until you give access to other users. To give a specific user access to the `sudo` command you have to run the `visudo` command as root, i.e. `sudo visudo`, and edit the file correspondingly. Some examples of how to give specific users access can be found [here](https://www.unixtutorial.org/2014/07/how-to-use-visudo/).

Comment: Ah, Eliah beat me to it, and his answer is more thourough.

Comment: That's okay -- the information is presented somewhat differently in each of our answers, and there's value in brevity, so I think this answer is helpful.